# Since when did Vote Count indicate the correct answer to the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation, up-votes

Really!
          We find highest voted answers to the questions often not conveying the point or answering the direct question.

I find *Vote count is more of a popularity contest ,rather than what seemingly answers the direct question better*.

Hence we find questions with no votes but answers to those questions with insanely high up votes.

> **Question:** What kind of moderation-regulation
>   check is there regarding this?

I am not trying to be a spoil sport or any thing but it would be nice to have direct answers to questions when you are really looking for simple and straightforward answers to issues.

**This may be the reason we see duplicate threads of similar topic. as the topic poster does not find satisfactory answers in similar/duplicate threads.**

Comment: @Anna i cant seem to post any thing here that does not include a feature-request or a bug tag.

Comment: You should be able to include `discussion` and `support` tags as well. If you can't, please report that on the [main Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since never. *Voting up* just says that you agree to the answer itself, and a high voted answer doesn't mean that it is the right one.

Duplicate threads are a part of what we do. A great part of the issue is that people are too lazy to search and rely on the goodness of our hearts to get an immediate answer. And that simply works.

Another problem is that sometimes even if you do try to search an answer for your problem before posting it, you might just miss one keyword that will prevent you from finding the similar question. This happened to me many times before.

Comment: +1 on missing the right keyword

Comment: or more rarely 2 people post basically the same question at the same time, or a question you think isn't related to something else actually is to people with more insight.